# how can json_decode string whitout change my longint value?

Tags: php, json, long-integer

I have a "json" string that contain long int value when i want to json_decode long int value changes to  float(3.6677890000187E+14)
help me please
thanks

Comment: Check the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php: `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`

Comment: use `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` constant as second para of `json_decode`

Comment: @KunalAwasthi helpful,thank you

Comment: Welcome @Sepideh

Comment: @jeroen helpful,thank you

Comment: can i post answer ? :D haha

Comment: @KunalAwasthi sure,why not :D

Answer (score 1):

use `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` as 2nd argument for `json_decode` like below

`json_decode($str, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)`

[php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING not work alone i try json_decode($str, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)